# Can we eliminate the pronoun after the verb to be?

Tags: grammar

I know we can omit a relative pronoun when it’s not the subject of the clause:

“There’s something you should know.”

But we can’t omit it when it’s the subject:

“The student who sits in the back of the room asks a lot of questions.”

But can we eliminate it in this sentence’s structure:

“The best side of her personality was she was kind.”

Comment: In writing, no: was that she was kind. In speech, people can get away with it. There might be a pause after the first was...she was kind.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: There are several instances in Google Books of [***"Any man says that is a liar"***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Any+man+says+that+is+a+liar%22), but I must admit they mostly seem to be pedagogic (*teaching* textbooks) - probably specifically pointing out that there should be a ***who*** or ***that*** "reprising" the subject ***Any man***. But it would be misguided pedantry to suppose there "should" be a ***that*** in your ***she was kind*** example. That one is completely optional, *always*.

Comment: As James K says in his answer, there is no relative clause in "The best side of her personality was [she was kind].” The bracketed element is a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "be".

Comment: @BillJ thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [There's a guy works down the chop shop swears he's Elvis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_a_Guy_Works_Down_the_Chip_Shop_Swears_He%27s_Elvis) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no relative clause in the sentence.

Adjectives can attach to nouns as pre-modifiers (a red apple), or they can be the complement in the sentence with a linking verb (The apple is red).  Relative clauses only attach as postmodifiers "an apple that is red". It isn't possible to use a relative clause as a complement (*the apple is that is red)

Now there are also content clauses.  These can look very similar to relative clauses, but instead of modifying a noun, they form part of the "content" of the clause as an object or the subject.

> I know {who did it}.

The content clause "who did it" completes the clause and is licenced by the verb "know".

Declarative content clauses are marked with "that", however the marker "that" is often optional.

> I hear (that) they've started dating.

That is the situation here.  The content clause "(that) she is kind" may be marked with "that", but it isn't required. In a simple example like this one, it could be omitted, but in a more complex sentence, it would be useful to mark the content clause with "that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation! I wasn’t sure I could eliminate that after the verb to be.

Answer (score 3):

In writing, no: was **that** she was kind.

In speech, people can get away with it. There might be a pause after the first was...she was kind.

"The best side of her personality was...she was kind.”

OR

"The best side of her personality was: she was kind.” [in writing, but without that]

Comment: I don't accept that ***that*** is "required" in "formal" writing. Whether or not to include it in contexts like OP's final example is *always* a stylistic choice, nothing to do with "level of formality".

Comment: "The best side of her personality was she was kind.” sounds pretty hokey to me. And I might even say it myself but I would never write it. Stylistic choice is often about level of formality, innit?

Comment: Sure. I'm not suggesting it's *always a **good** stylistic choice* to omit ***that*** in such contexts. Just that it's not really a matter of formal / informal - the reason it looks "awkward" in the *written* version is simply because at first glance the sequence ***was she was*** is awkward to parse *visually*. That's presumably why you included a colon, but I'm far from convinced that's "suitable" punctuation. In the *spoken* version (formal OR informal),  there would probably be *no pause at all* within those three words (which *wouldn't* give the audience "pause for thought"! :)